# ag-grid v19 filters are not retained

Tags: ag-grid

We were using ag-Grid v9. We updated to ag-Grid v19. 
We have a drop down in which multiple categories are loaded, we can select one category at a time and its data is loaded in the ag-Grid. 
We apply column filters for a selected category and respective rows get filtered. However when we change the category the applied filters are not retained. 
Earlier with v9 it was working correctly 
Earlier we were using OnAfterFilterChanged() but with v19 it got deprecated so we are using onFilterChanged()

Comment: hard to identify where the problem is without looking at some sample code

Answer (score 0):

To retain the state of grid filters, sort etc we should update data rather than replace data.

Use the grid property `deltaRowDataMode=true`

Very nicely explained in the article [DataUpdate](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-data-update/)